# How has sharding become easier in mysql now(in 2022) as compared to before?

Tags: mysql, database, sharding

I was currently implementing a side project where I had to make a choice for database. The basic considerations are listed below:

1. The schema is not strict and could have many empty fields.
2. There should be an easy way to have fuzzy text search.
3. It should scale horizontally with minimal work.
4. It only has one entity on which insertion and text searching needs to be performed.

I first evaluated MySQL but was turned away from it because of points 2 and 3. Also 1 implied that a document based database could work here. I learned from searching through various articles that for mySQL:

1. Text index though supported will not work in partitioned(or sharded) tables. ([reference](https://severalnines.com/database-blog/full-text-searches-mysql-good-bad-and-ugly))
2. Even with text indexes fuzzy searching will not be very straightforward to implement.

So I made the choice of using mongoDB in this scenario. But then I read [this](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/01/14/have-the-tables-turned-on-nosql/) article which mentions that horizontal scaling has become easier on mySQL compared to before.

As per my understanding for horizontal scaling in mySQL you need to specify sharding key which will require changes at application layer.

Is there a better way to achieve horizontal scaling with the considerations that I have listed earlier.

Update:

1. The primary queries will involve text searching over two columns.
2. Want to have an easy way to shard the db. (not partition)

Comment: no you use a sqlproxy that handles the incoming sql statements ad sends it depending of rules, it is independent how many server you have, the synstax takes of course some learning effort. Replication is faily easy, but hasn't changed that much. both techniques are handles in DAtabaseadministration and so you should ask there if you have **specific** questions.

Comment: It's more important to consider the **queries** you will need to write than the type of data. If you didn't have to consider queries, then sharding would be easy. Do it any way you want. E.g. fill up shard 1, then fill up shard 2, and so on. But that won't be best for the queries you need to execute. So start with the queries, and that will influence your choice of sharding architecture and the technology product that makes it easiest to implement that architecture.

Comment: "Partitioning" is splitting up a table in the same database.  "Sharding" is splitting the data across multiple servers.  Please clarify which you desire.

Comment: Consider MariaDB with the "Spider" engine.

Comment: @RickJames have updated the description based on your comments.

Comment: @BillKarwin have updated the description based on your comment. want to primarily do text searching on two columns.

Comment: Great, you're a step closer, but you need to identify _specific_ queries. When you have identified those queries, you can evaluate different sharding architectures to see if they handle those queries well.

Comment: @chain_of_dogs - What percent of the data in included in those two columns?  (I am thinking about extracting just the search criteria into a separate table.)  What key would you shard on?  Do you expect to grow beyond a mere 2 shards -- the overhead of 2 shards would probably wipe out the benefit of sharding.